# Django - directly using the Model class to avoid writing a Form class explicitely

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Currently prototyping for a Django app. I have code that defines a model and a form, which I then use to have users enter new instances in the DB. For instance:

models.py

```
class Produits(models.Model):
    no_prod = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    descfr = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    prix1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    prix2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=None)
```

forms.py

```
class CreateProduct(forms.Form):
    no_prod = forms.CharField(max_length=70)
    descfr = forms.CharField(max_length=70)
    cost = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    prix1 = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    prix2 = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

views.py

```
def create_product(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateProduct(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # create a product
            p = Produits(**form.cleaned_data)
            p.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/soum/produits')       # let's say go back to product list or something
    else:
        form = CreateProduct()
    return render(request, 'soum/produitsform.html', {'form': form})
```

That works all right.

However, the form & the model fields are exactly the same. In fact in the application a number of classes in the models may map one to one in this way. Is there a clever way in Django simplify the code above, so that "by default" I could just create a form that directly uses a model, and then only make explicit forms for those classes that don't map 1 to 1?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform

Comment: Ok ok, didn't know it was going to be all that obvious to Django devs. One sometimes wonder if we're still meant to ask question on SO these days... (cmts on the downvotes, not on your link...)

Comment: I would say it was downvoted for lack of research prior to asking it, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: I do get that. I didn't find it. Could I have looked longer? Sure. But then, one could take most question on SO and at some point the answer is probably mentioned in the docs somewhere. So depending on where we put the goalpost, we could pretty much downvote 80% of the questions based on that criteria. I just feel that SO is sometimes, as a community, overzealous even on well-formatted decent questions. Maybe I'm being laxed. Maybe ideal is somewhere in-between...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use `ModelForm`:

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Produits
```

Et le tour est joué : )

Edit: from here you can choose a subselection of fields from your model, that you only want to make available in your form:

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Produits
        fields = ['descfr', 'prix1']
```